# What is the cognitive bias called where you put an ethical boundary just above where you are?

Tags: bias

What is the cognitive bias called where you put an ethical boundary just above where you are?

It's where people often say that something is morally acceptable to do something up to a certain point in which in then becomes immoral/unethical, however they come up with that boundary based on how immoral of a thing they are okay doing themselves and it doesn't have to be immoral, for example:

A person who illegally downloads books says the only type of pirating that is acceptable is for books.

A person who smokes 10 packs of cigarettes a month says it's okay to smoke 10 packs of cigarettes a month and no more.

I'm not sure if this is an official bias but I remember watching a documentary and this came up, but I forgot what they referred to it as and what the documentary was called *facepalm*.

Comment: It’s like a  slippery slope variant, involving (avoiding) cognitive dissonance regarding one’s own self image.